# Uploading an image to sqlsrv database causing error

Tags: php, laravel, stored-procedures, pdo, sqlsrv

I am currently uploading an image to a sqlsrv database (this is the only option for this piece of work). I am getting the contents of the file, converting it to base64.

```
$imageContents = file_get_contents($uploadedLogoPath);
$this->Logo = base64_encode($imageContents);
```

After this I am uploading it using a stored procedure:

```
return DB::statement("EXEC myStoredProcedure
        ....
        @Logo = ?"
    [
        ...
        $this->Logo
    ];
);
```

However, when I am using data binding for the stored procedure I get the following error:

> nvarchar(max) is incompatible with image

But, when I do not use data binding and add the logo directly, it works:

```
return DB::statement("EXEC myStoredProcedure
        ...
        @Logo = '" . $this->Logo . "' ")
```

What is going on here to cause this? How can I get this to work with data binding please (so that it is not vulnerable to SQL injection).

Comment: If `$this->Logo` type-hinted in any way?

Comment: @ChrisHaas no it's not